# php-cgi won't install

Tags: apt, php

When I try to install the `php-cgi` package, using `sudo apt-get install php-cgi`, I receive the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php-cgi : Depends: php7.2-cgi but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any problems with that particular package. However, that being said,here are the generic `apt` fixes:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt update
```

and try again. If the problem persists, try removing the packages

```
sudo apt purge php-cgi
```

if that comes up with errors, use `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg --remove php-cgi
```

then try `apt` again:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

then try installing again.